# using the word chick in PHP?

Tags: php, phpmailer

This is currently the most bizarre issue I have faced with PHP. I have a newsletter send facility on a clients website that has worked for years. This months newsletter wouldn't send and after hours of investigating I narrowed it down to one word within one of the articles in the newsletter. The word in question - 'chick'!

Changing the word to chicken works, ch ick works, c hick works......, it's just chick! Being Easter soon they want to send an article about an Easter chick hunt.

I have tried different encoding, checked for invisible characters, checked what's being inputted into the database, upgraded the mail system to use PHPMailer but the only thing that works is changing the word chick!

If anyone has any idea what could be causing this I would love to hear from you!

Thanks.

Comment: That cannot be what's causing the trouble. What code have you got?

Comment: Could you please define "wouldn't send"?

Comment: It is likely that this is caused by a filter on the SMTP server, which logs should give you more information.

Comment: I suppose that the server think its spam, because chick is used in ... SPECIAL mails about women with ... SPECIAL needs.

Comment: This won't be anything to do with PHP. I guess there's a system in place that blocks "bad" words. It clearly isn't part of your code, so I guess it's tied to either the system that you're using to send your email or the one that is receiving it. Either way, there's not much you can do about it in the context of the PHP code; you'll need to talk to the people who are running the email filtering software. This kind of issue is a good demonstration of why systems like that are a bad idea; there are just too many issues with false positives. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: Look in your spam folder. Alternatively, look at saying `easter hunt` or `easter chick-hunt` or something.

Comment: Thanks to all for speedy replies. I agree the spam route is the most likely answer, but I have checked my spam and junk folders but nothing's there.

Comment: @Lix There are no errors it just doesn't appear in my inbox.

Comment: I hadn't made the 'chick' / babes / girls connection as I had Easter in my head, this is very logical explanation. Will post back the response from hosting company. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was the hosting company blocking the word chick at their end. They've amended their spam filters and it now sends!

Thanks to all taking the time to comment.

Comment: +1 for sticking it to the PC brigade! What a complete and utter nonsense, the world has gone mad...